# PHP Sort Files In Directory by Type

Tags: php, sorting, directory

I wrote the following PHP code to display files in a directory. It uses JQuery to expand folders. Everything works fine but right now it displays all files in alphabetical order mixing file types.

I'd like to keep the alphabetical order but display folders and files separately. How can I sort the displayed files so Folders are displayed on top and other files are displayed bellow.

In other words, how do I sort the files by file type?

Thank you very much!

```
<?php
$path = ROOT_PATH;
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");
list_dir($dir_handle,$path);

function list_dir($dir_handle,$path)
{
    echo "<ul class='treeview'>";

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) 
    {
        $dir =$path.'/'.$file;
        if(is_dir($dir) && $file != '.' && $file !='..' )
        {
            $handle = @opendir($dir) or die("undable to open file $file");
            echo '<li class="folder"><a href="#" class="toggle">'.$file.'</a></li>';
            list_dir($handle, $dir);
        }
        elseif($file != '.' && $file !='..')
        {
            echo '<li class="file"><a href="file-details.php?file='.$dir.'" class="arrow_icon modal">'.$file.'</a></li>';
        }
    }

    echo "</ul>";

    closedir($dir_handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you should do is separate the logic of getting/sorting the files and displaying them, that'll make customisation easier..

Here's a working solution (had some spare time this morning :)

```
list_dir(ROOT_PATH);

/* Rendering */
function list_dir($path)
{
   $items = get_sorted_entries($path);

    if (!$items)
        return;

    echo "<ul class='treeview'>";


    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        if ($item->type=='dir')
        {
            echo '<li class="folder"><a href="#" class="toggle">'.$item->entry.'</a></li>';
            list_dir($item->full_path);
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<li class="file"><a href="file-details.php?file='.urlencode($item->full_path).'" class="arrow_icon modal">'.$item->entry.'</a></li>';
        }
    }

    echo "</ul>";

}

/* Finding */
function get_sorted_entries($path)
{
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) ;
    $items = array();

    while (false !== ($item = readdir($dir_handle))) 
    {
        $dir =$path.'/'.$item;
        if ( $item == '.' || $item =='..' )
            continue;

        if(is_dir($dir))
        {
            $items[] = (object) array('type'=>'dir','entry'=>$item, 'full_path'=>$dir);
        }
        else
        {
            $items[] = (object) array('type'=>'file','entry'=>$item, 'full_path'=>$dir);
        }
    }
    closedir($dir_handle);

    usort($items,'_sort_entries');

    return $items;
}

/* Sorting */
function _sort_entries($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->entry,$b->entry);
}
```

**Edit**: And if you want to show the directories first, change the sort function to this:

```
function _sort_entries($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->type!=$b->type)
        return strcmp($a->type,$b->type);

    return strcmp($a->entry,$b->entry);
}
```

That will put the directories at the top (Windows style)

Comment: @usnidorg. No probs. Edited my post with a slight variation for directories at the top

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted to do.