# How do I list only selected level in directory recursive list?

Tags: php, recursion, treeview, arraylist, recursive-datastructures

I use this code: [PHP Sort Files In Directory by Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588798/php-sort-files-in-directory-by-type/5588942#5588942)

But it opens up all directories. I just want directories that leads to the selected item to be open.

Answer (score 0):

If im understanding you correctly, you don't want to recursively display the directories under the target. I think you would remove the recursive call from the code above like this :

```
/* Rendering */
function list_dir($path)
{

    ...

    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        if ($item->type=='dir')
        {
            echo '<li class="folder"><a href="#" class="toggle">'.$item->entry.'</a></li>';
            //list_dir($item->full_path); REMOVE THIS
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<li class="file"><a href="file-details.php?file='.urlencode($item->full_path).'" class="arrow_icon modal">'.$item->entry.'</a></li>';
        }
    }

    echo "</ul>";

}
```

Comment: I want the recursive function to be there. But when I arrive to the page the folders sholud be closed. And when I click on a folder, the page will be reload and the folder open. In the code above, with recursive functionality, all subfodlers will also be open. I want the navigation functionality. It is not a site map.

Comment: Oh, you need to write the javascript for that then. The original post you linked to said he used jQuery to open and close folders, and the "toggle", "folder" and "treeview" classes are the targets you need to look at. I'd recommend messaging him to see if you could get the js for it.